# Adding [CDATA[ element in an XML

Tags: plsql

I was asked to generate an XML, extracting data from a table, but adding the [CDATA[ element.
I have done in the following manner:

```
select   XMLTYPE
          (
           replace(
           replace(replace(xmlelement("TAG1",
           xmlelement("TAG2",col1),
           xmlelement("TAGX",
           xmlelement("TAG3",
           xmlelement("TAG4",col2)))).extract('/*') ,'/TAGX',']]'),'TAGX','![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?'),
           '<]]>',']]>')
          )
into XMLdoc
from MYTABLE;
```

where col1 and col2 are MYTABLE's columns

Is it possible to do in a smarter way instead of using the work-around of the REPLACE?

The result should be this:

```
<TAG1>
 <TAG2> 15 </TAG2>
 <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <TAG3>
   <TAG4> Rodgers </TAG4>
  </TAG3>
 ]]>
</TAG1>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [XMLCDATA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions216.htm).

```
SELECT
  XMLELEMENT("TAG1",
    XMLELEMENT("TAG2",col1),
    XMLCDATA(
      XMLELEMENT("TAG3",
        XMLELEMENT("TAG4",col2)
      )
    )
  )
INTO XMLDoc
FROM MYTABLE;
```

Result:

```
<TAG1><TAG2>15</TAG2><![CDATA[<TAG3><TAG4>Rodgers</TAG4></TAG3>]]></TAG1>
```

You can use [XMLSERIALIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions268.htm#SQLRF06231) to include the XML Declaration within the XMLCDATA if required.

Comment: Thank you very much Matt.
One more question
I see that I can't have the line <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> on a new line.
I have tried to put the .extract('/*') in every place but it doesn't seem to work . How can I get every TAG on a new line for a more readable XML?

Comment: Depending on your Oracle version, you may be able to use XMLSERIALIZE to indent too. I believe Oracle 11g introduced this. (e.g. XMLSERIALIZE(DOCUMENT <xml> AS CLOB INDENT SIZE = 4)

Comment: Thanks Matt, but I work on Oracle 10gR2 and it seems that XMLSERIALIZE didn't exist yet ,,,